# "Undefined" Tabs included in RMarkdown tabsets?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When I knit my RMarkdown document to an HTML file my tabs look like they do below:

[image]

However, when I save the document to share with my audience the file now includes these tabs that are marked as "undefined". To be clear, the issues occurs when I save the document locally to my computer.

[image]

**Below is an example of my tabset logic**

```
# Introduction {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
     
## Open Quotes  {.tabset .tabset-pills}
   
## Late Orders  {.tabset .tabset-pills}
```

Comment: I can reproduce this following the steps provided by @Waldi . If the problem already happens with the original HTML file output (and not just with a secondary export from the browser), it could help to specify the `self_contained: true` in the header.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the problem with following steps:

1. knit document and generate `test.html`

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: true
---

# Introduction {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
     
## Open Quotes  
   
## Late Orders
```

2. open `test.html` in browser
   [image]
3. save `test.html` from browser to `saved_from_browser.html`

The browser creates :

1. a new `saved_from_browser.html` file
2. **an associated directory** `saved_from_browser_files` containing `MathJax.js`

The problem occurs if you open `saved_from_browser.html` without the associated directory (for example after deleting it) :

[image]

If you have access to the original `test.html` file, use it for sharing as it is **self-contained**.
If not, don't forget to supply the associated directory.

Comment: Thanks Waldi. I'll admit I don't fully understand your answer but at least now I know how to recreate this problem and how to avoid it. My simple workaround to avoid the undefined tabs is to simply rename the *.nb html file in file explorer and not save the html file from the browser. That is good enough for now.